# scrollTop not working even with overflow-x:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://jamesdaltonportfolio.herokuapp.com/

So here is my portfolio site. I am trying to make the page scroll to specific divs when links are clicked on the nav bar

I tried removing `overflow-x:hidden;` on the `body`, but that did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// $("#about-button").click(function() {
    // $(window).scrollTop($("#projects-container").offset().top);
// });


$('#about-button').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#about-container').offset().top
}, 1000);
}); 

});
```

I even tried console.logging the `#about-containers` scrollTop property and the value was '0'. I felt that was strange since the vertical position of the scrollbar has to be greater than 0. This is driving me nuts. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted looks different than the code on your website:
https://jamesdaltonportfolio.herokuapp.com/assets/javascript/app.js

Comment: sorry, here is the new link https://jamesdaltonportfolio.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link refreshes the page because of the `<a href="">` attribute.

Add a # to it:

```
<a href="#" id="about-button" data-target="about-container">About</a>
```

Comment: No kidding. All of that fuss over nothing. Thank you!